# How I can upgrade my Ubuntu python3.7 to python3.8 latest version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-19.04

I am tried by this command

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade python
```

but still, it did not work.

Comment: That's for updating libraries installed in Python, not Python itself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`pip` is not capable of upgrading python - it is for [python packages](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/). Use,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.8
```

On Ubuntu. You may also want `-dev` and `-venv`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-venv python3.8-dev
```

To ensure you have 3.8 `pip`, `virtualenv`, and such.

Comment: To install python on Ubuntu 14.04. You may not be able to install python3.8. Which python version you can install you can check with  `apt-cache search python3.7`. If prompt returns without output, python3.7 can not be installed, try installing a lower version of python.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install python3.8
```

And if you want to replace the 3.7 with 3.8 for the python3 on your computer use the following after running the above commands.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1

sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 2
```

You can switch between python versions on your computer by running the following command.
This will show you the installed versions and you can select which one you want to use.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

Comment: But I can't use my previously installed libraries in python3.8

Comment: @Shiva_Adasule, Yes. You are correct. When you upgrade your your Python version, you will need to also reinstall any libraris you use at the SYSTEM level.

The correct way to manage this for individual projects is to use virtualenvs where both the version of python and the libraries are maintained for that specific project\application. Lots about that online.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sudo apt --fix-missing purge $(dpkg -l | grep 'python3\.7' | awk '{print $2}')
```

then run

```
sudo apt upgrade
```